# R how to change one of the level to NA

Tags: r, r-factor

I have a data set and one of its column has factor levels `"a" "b" "c" "NotPerformed"`. How can I change all the `"NotPerformed"` factors to NA?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Set the level to NA:

```
x <- factor(c("a", "b", "c", "NotPerformed"))
x
## [1] a            b            c            NotPerformed
## Levels: a b c NotPerformed
levels(x)[levels(x)=='NotPerformed'] <- NA
x
## [1] a    b    c    <NA>
## Levels: a b c
```

Note that the factor level is removed.

Comment: As a side-note, while `x[x=="NotPerformed"] <- NA` will replace the values with `NA`, it will not remove the `'NotPerformed'` factor level. Which is why this method is preferable.

Answer (score 9):

I revise my old answer and provide what you can do as of September 2016. With the development of the `dplyr` package, now you can use `recode_factor()` to do the job.

```
x <- factor(c("a", "b", "c", "NotPerformed"))

# [1] a            b            c            NotPerformed
# Levels: a b c NotPerformed

library(dplyr)
recode_factor(x, NotPerformed = NA_character_)
# [1] a    b    c    <NA>
# Levels: a b c
```

Comment: This can be updated to include the `forcats` package: `fct_recode(x, NULL = "NotPerformed")`.

Answer (score 7):

Or simply use the inbuilt `exclude` option, which works regardless of whether the initial variable is a character or factor.

```
x <- c("a", "b", "c", "NotPerformed")

factor(x, exclude = "NotPerformed")
[1] a    b    c    <NA>
Levels: a b c

factor(factor(x), exclude = "NotPerformed")
[1] a    b    c    <NA>
Levels: a b c
```

Comment: Many years using R and I never saw this before. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Set one of the levels to `NA` through `tidyverse` **Pipeline**, `%>%`.
This may serve better as a comment, but I do not have that many reputation.
In my case, the `income` variable is `int` with values of `c(1:7, 9)`. Among the levels, "9" represents "Do not wish to answer".

```
## when all int should be fctr 
New_data <- data %>% mutate_if(is.integer, as.factor)  %>% 
mutate(income = fct_recode(income, NULL = "9"))
```

I also tried `recode()`, it does not work.