# Recode NA factor with dplyr or forcats

Tags: r, dplyr, forcats

I am trying to recode a single factor from `NA` to a string using the `forcats` or `dplyr` package in `tidyverse`. The problem I'm having is that the factor I am trying to change is an `NA` value and I'm running into an error.

I found this question ([R how to change one of the level to NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354964/r-how-to-change-one-of-the-level-to-na)) that's changing a factor TO `NA` but I'm trying to change it FROM `NA`.

Here's what I tried:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Units) %>% 
  summarize(Frequency = n(), 
            Total = sum(Responses, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  mutate(Units = recode_factor(Units, "No Response" = NA_character_))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  Units     Frequency Total
  <fct>         <int> <dbl>
1 (0,3]             4     8
2 (3,10]            5    31
3 (10,30]           2    38
4 (100,Inf]         3   673
5 NA                1     0
Warning messages:
1: Problem with `mutate()` input `Units`.
i Unknown levels in `f`: NA
i Input `Units` is `fct_recode(Units, `No Response` = NA_character_)`. 
2: Unknown levels in `f`: NA
```

And

```
library(forcats)
df %>% 
  group_by(Units) %>% 
  summarize(Frequency = n(), 
            Total = sum(Responses, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  mutate(Units = fct_recode(Units, "No Response" = NA_character_))

`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  Units     Frequency Total
  <fct>         <int> <dbl>
1 (0,3]             4     8
2 (3,10]            5    31
3 (10,30]           2    38
4 (100,Inf]         3   673
5 NA                1     0
```

Sample Data:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("000002", "000008", "000009", "000018", 
"000021", "000033", "000045", "000051", "000064", "000067", "000070", 
"000072", "000074", "000088", "000112"), Responses = c(18, 6, 
300, 8, 7, 150, 6, 4, 2, 3, 20, NA, 223, 2, 1), Units = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, NA, 5L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("(0,3]", 
"(3,10]", "(10,30]", "(30,100]", "(100,Inf]"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `fct_explicit_na` which is written specially to handle `NA` values.

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

df %>% 
  group_by(Units) %>% 
  summarize(Frequency = n(), 
            Total = sum(Responses, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  mutate(Units = fct_explicit_na(Units, "No Response"))

#  Units       Frequency Total
#* <fct>           <int> <dbl>
#1 (0,3]               4     8
#2 (3,10]              5    31
#3 (10,30]             2    38
#4 (100,Inf]           3   673
#5 No Response         1     0
```

You can also include the new level in your data and then use `replace` to change `NA` values.

```
levels(df$Units) <- c(levels(df$Units), "No Response")

df %>% 
  group_by(Units) %>% 
  summarize(Frequency = n(), 
            Total = sum(Responses, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  mutate(Units = replace(Units, is.na(Units), "No Response"))
```

Comment: Hi @Ronak do you have to group_by and summarize first or can you just do this: 
df %>% 
  mutate(Units = replace(Units, is.na(Units), "No Response"))

Comment: Order is not important here, it can be done in any order.

Comment: also available with `dplyr`: `mutate(Units = na_if(Units, "No Response"))`

Comment: `fct_explicit_na()` was deprecated in forcats 1.0.0. Can use `fct_na_value_to_level()` instead.